# How can I start a boost Thread running a class function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-thread

im doing a C++ class where, internally, i want to create a thread to execute a function of the class, how can I do this? I show you some code.

Member function i want to run in a thread:

```
void SocketServer::runServer(){
    bool connected;
    tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), puerto));
    std::string data;

    while(seguirFuncionando()){
        miSocket = new tcp::socket(io_service);
        std::cout << "Waiting for connection...\n";
        a.accept(*miSocket);
        std::cout << "Connected\n";
        connected = true;
        try{
            while (connected){
                data = readStr();
                if (data.compare("")==0){
                    std::cout << "End of connection.\n";
                }
                else{
                    std::cout << data << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e){
        std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

What im trying to do:

```
void SocketServer::runThreadServer(){
    asio::thread t(runServer);
}
```

But it doesnt compile. Error:

no matching function for call to 'asio::thread::thread()
note: candidates are: asio::thread::thread(Function) [with Function = void (SocketServer::*)()]

How should i do this?

Thanx.

Comment: You might want to try with [boost.bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/bind/bind.html)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Could you give me an example? Im new with boost, and im a little lost :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Joachim Pileborg said, the standard way to do this is to use `boost::bind`. `boost::bind` specifically makes a construct named `boost::function` (which may be passed in the c'tor of `boost::thread`) from a C++ object and its member function.

Something like this:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&SocketServer::runServer, this));
```

Comment: Thanx, that worked fine :) Thanx valdo and Joachim. Another thing, where could i learn well about boost Threads and Asio? Im developing a client-server app, and i need to handle this very well, but the official doc is not very extensive. Where can i get good examples? Thanx

Comment: To be precise, `boost::bind` does NOT create `boost::function` objects, it creates objects of an *unknown* (undocumented, can change any time) type that can be assigned to a `boost::function` of the appropriate signature.